# NetBeans 17 for applications needing JDK8

Tags: netbeans, java-8

Is it possible to code Java applications having JDK8 source / binary format in NetBeans 17 which runs under JDK11?

We have Java applications which were developed for JDK8 and should not be
updated with regards to Source / Binary Format.
But we would like to upgrade the environment from NetBeans 8.2 to a newer one.
So we would install and run NetBeans 17 with JDK11+ but continue coding the
apps having Source / Binary format set as JDK8.

Is that possible?

Comment: Are you saying you're developing with Java 11+, but want to target Java 8? You should be able to do that with `--release 8` during compilation, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Netbeans 17 needs JDK11 to run. But the application you're developping with Netbeans can use an older version. This is set in the Properties of your project.

For example see below for a Ant-based Java application (my NB runs on JDK17 that's why you see more choices):

[image]